# How do I point tfs-git to a new path in the same tfs repository?

Tags: git, git-tfs

I am using git-tfs to manage my source control.  It was decided that the code that I am working on would be moved to a new location within the TFS repository.

I would like to point git-tfs to the new location so that I do not have to clone from the new path and can continue referencing the old history.

Is this possible and if so how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It was decided that the code that I am working on would be moved to a new location within the TFS repository.

Is it a rename of the source folder? or source code has been copied in a new directory?

If you are in the 2nd case, that's not supported by git-tfs because there is not link between the 2 folders in TFS.

If that's the 1st case, there is a support of this case but not in the current released version :(

You will have to build a developpement version and run it. [This one](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/pull/480)

After that, the code should be :

```
git tfs branch --init $/Name/Of/Your/New/Folder
```

edit: I forgot a more interesting 3rd case: the new folder is the result of a branching from the original folder (it's what it should be if they have done their work well!). In this case, you just have to use the same command :

```
git tfs branch --init $/Name/Of/Your/New/Folder
```

but don't have to build your own version because it's already supported in the current stable version v 0.19.2 of git-tfs.

I hope you could go with that...

Comment: It was a copy, so no luck.